# Page navigation on Users page doesn't work if using the input box

Tags: bug, status-completed, navigation, users-page

### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to the [Users page on Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users)
2. Type a name into the input box with lots of results ("anonymous", any firstname)
3. Try to navigate to the next page.

### Expected behaviour

The second page of the users list is displayed with all users named "anonymous".

### Effect

The inputbox is empty and the second page of **all** users is displayed.

### Additional information

Fx 3.0.11, JavaScript enabled, all Addons disabled.

I think it's a bug or a missing feature ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done.

No paging visible.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com/users
2. Click the "name" tab to sort the list by name
3. Either click the page navigation buttons, or edit the URL ( https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=302&tab=name ) , to arrive at the right letter

Comment: Clicking "name" tab gives strange user order. And it's definitely not alphabetical name order.

Comment: it is, but lots of users have no Display Name set.