# Improper pagination of user search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page navigation on Users page doesn’t work if using the input box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box)

When searching for a user without knowing the exact name, it shows paginated results of all matches. However if you try and navigate through these results they are automatically defaulted back to the reputation based sort. It's impossible to see any more than 35 matches for any search.

Suggestion:

1. Either remove the paginated results for user searches
2. Make them work :)

Comment: Maps to this uservoice item: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/229493-user-page-search-paging-bug

Comment: This is also an issue if looking for a person with a very common name, so even the complete username could result in multiple pages

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, results come from:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/filter/jo

But the links point to:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/users?page=num

Doesn't appear to be a &userFilter, &userfilter, or &filter variable for the GET method. Nor a page segement to the user-friendly method.