# Pagination for 'Type to find users' results does not work

Tags: bug, search, user-interface

On https://stackoverflow.com/users, type a couple letters ("Jo" for example), then click on [2] or [Next].  This takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2, which is the second page of all users sorted by reputation, not the second page of usernames containing the search text.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/improper-pagination-of-user-search

Comment: Duplicate "Possible Duplicate" links... very nice. :-)  I'll go ahead and log *that* as a bug also!

Comment: Someone [just did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272636/duplicate-on-possible-duplicate-in-a-post), more than 6 years later...