# Tag search state retention inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, trivial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pagination for ‘Type to find users’ results does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/pagination-for-type-to-find-users-results-does-not-work)

On the [tag search page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), text entered into the "Type to find tags:" search box is retained if you click on a tag in the search result set, then click your browser's back button, but the search result set itself is reset to the default set (most popular tags).  Retyping the last letter of the search text will rebuild the filter.  For a consistent user experience, either the search box should be cleared out upon revisiting the tag search page, or the matching result set should be reloaded.

Comment: This has bugged me too.