# minor quirk in "Tags" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag search state retention inconsistency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/tag-search-state-retention-inconsistency)

Small bug report. (actually, maybe more of a quirk than a bug?)

If you go to the "Tags" page, it loads with a set of page links at the bottom.

If you type anything into the search box, those links disappear. I can understand that: I guess the idea is that you refine your search until there's less than a page of tags.

However, if you then want to revert back to normal non-search mode, clearing out the search box is not enough to get you back to square one: the tags shown go back to the default first page of results, but the page buttons do not re-appear.

I know it's only a small quirk, but it caught me out, so I thought I'd report it.

Comment: closed as dup... fair enough. It didn't show up when I searched, but I guess I wasn't looking for words like 'retention inconsistency'. hehehe.  :)

Comment: This was actually a regression will be fixed with the next deploy

Comment: @waffles - thanks for the acknowledgement. :)

Comment: @waffles - since this wasn't a dup question after all, would it be of value to re-open it, or is that a pointless excersise now that it's been fixed anyway?

Comment: .. no point really ... it would just clutter meta a bit more.