# Duplicate on Possible Duplicate in a post

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

There is a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4991/312043) closed as Duplicate. But the **Possible Duplicate** content appears twice for the post, even the both links are pointed a [same post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1208/312043).

I never see a duplicate on possible duplicate content. Why it displays like this?

For future reference, I'm adding the screen shot:

[image: Possible Duplicate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably just some weirdness with how duplicates worked back then. We used to edit the text into the post on closure (rather than show the notice we have now), and it looks like [maybe the original closer double-clicked the button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4991/revisions)? Doesn't really matter now.

I reopened the question, edited out the "possible duplicate" blocks, and re-closed as duplicate.

Comment: Okay, then it's fine. Now it's looking normal.