# Filtered "Users" page loses filter when "next" button is clicked

Tags: bug, users, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page navigation on Users page doesn’t work if using the input box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box)

Scenario:

1. Open [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) page.
2. Type in a common name (something which will match more than one page of users--"peter" works).
3. Click the "next" button.

Expected: Page 2 of users matching "peter" is shown.

Actual: Page 2 of all users is shown.

*Also strange to me (but maybe by design): the filtered user list doesn't sort by rep like the unfiltered one does.*

Comment: This is a known issue. See here for workaround: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box