# Pagination wrong in Users page

Tags: bug, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page navigation on Users page doesn’t work if using the input box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box)

Here is what is wrong:

I type a name, let's say "rob", to search a user in the users page. It gives me about 2 pages. However, when I click "next page" or "page 2", it returns back to the page 2 of the whole list, not the page 2 of the users for "Rob".

It seems that this issue happens on all 3 sites.

Comment: this is a well-known bug. see here for a temporary workaround: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box