# When you filter the user list you lose the pagination bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, filtering, pagination, user-list

When you filter the user list by typing anything in the search box, the pagination bar dissapears, and it doesn't reappear until you refresh the page.

Even clearing the textbox doesn't work.

Comment: I doubt it will be fixed: [Page navigation on Users page doesn't work if using the input box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box)

Comment: @John: That is depressing.

Comment: status-completed = problem-diverted

Comment: status-completed = problem? what problem?

Comment: @John, hadn't seen that one... it is, actually, depressing... 6 to 8 weeks till a fix I guess

Comment: @TheTXI: I know, I know. After listening to the last podcast it's for sure that Jeff will never be a good tester. Lack of details...

Comment: "By Design": We all knew it...

Comment: The same thing occurs on the tags page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the build tonight the pagination will now reappear when clearing the search textbox.

Note: search results (e.g. something in the textbox) themselves will still not be paged (current behavior)...your search will still need to be more specific there.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been asked at least a half dozen times already, but I have never heard about anything being done to fix it.

Comment: I read a few question suggested when I typed the title, but none said it dissapears (I think)

Comment: The problem is pagination isn't supported on searched pages. The solution to this, I guess, was to remove it completely (lol).

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com/users
2. Click the "name" tab to sort the list by name
3. Either click the page navigation buttons, or edit the URL ( https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=302&tab=name ) , to arrive at the right letter

Comment: This is not a suitable workaround if one is searching for a substring in the middle of the name, rather than at the beginning.

Comment: @ether searching for substrings is no longer possible on SO due to the size of the user table.

Comment: booooo. but understandable.  If it was important, one could cache a substring parse tree, but this is not a key feature of the site. (It's far more important to be able to properly search for content.)