# User search results are incomplete

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, user-accounts

A little while ago (before he changed his name again) I went looking to find out what [Downvoter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1782?tab=accounts#tab-top) had changed his name to on meta, so I went to search for "Manuel" on SO (to find his 'related accounts' to come back to his meta name). To my surprise, no results came up, even though [his account clearly exists](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782/juan-manuel-formoso) and the search text should match.

Reproduction steps:

- go to the [SO user search page](https://stackoverflow.com/users)
- search for 'manuel'
- observe the lack of the [desired match](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782/juan-manuel-formoso)

This could be simply a lack of a "page 2" link, since there are sufficient matches to fill the page.  (If results were sorted by reputation, then Juan Manuel would appear at the top of the search results, but he should at least be *somewhere*.)

Comment: There isn't any paging when you search (oh how I wish there was on a tag search). I'd suggest turning this into a feature request (probably a good idea to search first).

Comment: Related: [When you filter the user list you lose the pagination bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/when-you-filter-the-user-list-you-lose-the-pagination-bar)

Comment: Sigh, another [status-nope-we're-not-going-to-fix-it] bug.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you only get as far as "manue", he'll actually show up.

It seems that it prioritizes people who match the name completely. If you look at the leftmost column (all Emanuels) from the "manue" search, you might recognize it as the rightmost column that occurs in the "manuel" search. Everyone before that is just named "Manuel". So my guess is, the search prioritizes those Manuels first. When it is done, it'll use the normal algorithm, and as you note this fills up the page before you can reach Juan Manuel Formoso.

[image: He's circled in red. The green is the matching column]