# Does Jon Skeet exist?

Tags: support, search, user-accounts

Clearly, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is a Stack Overflow user, but why doesn't this user name appear when typing "Skeet" on the [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) (illustrated below)?

---

[image]

Comment: psst, dont tell anyone: he is a ghost...

Comment: I bet it works when Jon Skeet tries it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User search results are incomplete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53351/user-search-results-are-incomplete)

Comment: I don't know what changed, but now typing `Skeet` does show Jon.

Comment: Is this post off-topic.......?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was originally going to link some of the earlier posts which explain some of the oddities of the User Search (which prioritizes exact matches, like [shown here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53351/user-search-results-are-incomplete/53352#53352)).

However, it turns out that the algorithm was changed for Stack Overflow at some point. Search now only checks for strings that begin with the specified string. So for example, I won't find [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274402/ccomet) if I search for "comet".

Comment: No, the difference is just SO <-> everywhere else; this isn't new. %string% searches aren't indexable, and with a userbase as large as SO, that makes a huge difference.

Comment: @balpha Ah, so this is by design? Interesting. It makes sense, though.

Comment: See [this answer by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60902/has-the-type-to-find-users-string-match-functionality-been-changed-deliberately/60947#60947) explaining that SO's user table has become too large to allow to support searching within the name.

Comment: @sepp2k Interesting. August is actually quite a while back, but then again, June is even further back, so...

Comment: umm, then what is full text search for?

Answer (score 10):

Probably because the search is:

```
select username from users where username like '<search_string>%'
```

not

```
select username from users where username like '%<search_string>%'
```

Answer (score 1):

A picture's worth a thousand words, right?

[image]