# Paging disappear on users page after search

Tags: bug, pagination, user-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When you filter the user list you lose the pagination bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/when-you-filter-the-user-list-you-lose-the-pagination-bar)

Open Users page. You can see page number on bottom right of the page. Search for user on Users page. Delete text from textbox using backspace. Paging does not appear until you refresh page.

Is this problem or it is implemented like that?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks duplicate but now it reappear if you remove filter and refresh page.

Comment: That remains the same report. Removing the filter is irrelevant - not removing it and refreshing yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**`[Status-By-Design]`**

According to [a previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box) here on meta.

Basically, instead of fixing a paging bug, they just removed paging.

Comment: well, it would actually be adding a feature, but since the vestigial tail confused people, it's simpler to remove it.