# Per-site meta "Users" tab filter is not functioning correctly with pagination

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, pagination, users-page

The selection of the "week/month/quarter/year/all" filter is not retained when applying the pagination in the "Users" page "Participation/Voters/Editors" tab on the per-site meta.

Steps to reproduce:

- I'm selecting the "Participation" tab "all" results: https://meta.superuser.com/users?tab=Participation&filter=all
- I'm navigating to the next page, by clicking on "Page 2" in the pagination section
- Now I'm expecting to navigate to page 2 with the filter selected as "all" https://meta.superuser.com/users?page=2&tab=Participation&filter=all but instead of that I got the navigation to the "quarter" tab: https://meta.superuser.com/users?page=2&tab=participation

In this case, `&filter=all` is missing in the URL, after applying the pagination.

**GIF for the same:**

[image: Filter not applied - GIF]

Comment: status-by-design: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80420/361484

Comment: This probably isn't @Luuklag - the option to choose the time period was just added a month or so ago on metas, so there does seem to be something going on here... likely what happened is that, because meta had no filter by timeframe, they forgot to retain it in the URL when switching between the pages.

Comment: Heck, that isn't even correct any more, as far as I can tell. You can search for usernames and go through as many pages of results as there are, so that answer seems to be outdated.

Comment: @jrjones thanks for fixing! For some rep (and fame ;)) please feel free to share some details in an answer. :)