# After clearing search for user text box, the next/previous buttons disappear

Tags: bug, status-declined

I'm not sure if anyone has filed this bug yet, but I can't find it on here. So

I searched for a user on the user page, then cleared that text box. Now the next/previous buttons are gone.

Comment: This is intentional (and a dupe but can't find).

Comment: And here's the dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box

Comment: @random, This is a bug, that was probably introduced by that bug fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional? Clearing the text box blowing away the buttons? I find that hard to believe. I replicated it -- it feels buggy to me, too.

Regarding the dupe:

This really **isn't** a dupe, it's more an elaboration on the question random linked. The question linked describes the behavior, and the fix was to remove paging when the input box is used. While I still think that is even buggy, I can understand it.

However, once the input box is cleared, as per this question, then the original behavior **should** be restored. After all, all you've done at that point is undo your original actions. At that point, it should be as if you never performed those actions -- but it's not. And therein is the bug.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you "think", it was removed intentionally as per the dupe posted by random.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing was brought up in yet another dupe. All these topics have been discussed and denied.

Comment: Link the other dupe; I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're filing as a bug, [it's status-bydesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/page-navigation-on-users-page-doesnt-work-if-using-the-input-box).

However, if you were to edit your question as wanting it to behave like you want it to, that's another thing entirely.

It would be good to see the pagination stick around if you're searching for a particular whathaveyou in the DisplayName.

But for now a workaround would be to query the [Public Data Dump](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) with [something like this](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=select%20concat%28%27%3Ca%20href=%22https://stackoverflow.com/users/%27%2C%20id%2C%20%27%22%3E%27%2C%20displayname%2C%20%27%3C/a%3E%27%29%20as%20author%2C%20reputation%20from%20users%20where%20displayname%20like%20%27%25cthulu%25%27%20%20order%20by%20displayname%20asc):

```
SELECT
 concat('<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/', Id, '">', 
                                  DisplayName, '</a>') as author, Reputation 
FROM users
WHERE DisplayName LIKE '%cthulu%'
ORDER BY DisplayName ASC
```

Pretty linking [ripped from Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/who-gets-the-most-reputation-per-keystroke-on-so/21497#21497).

Comment: How would this be status-bydesign? It doesn't make sense that even after your clear a textbox, the buttons do not come back so that I may navigate to another page. This just seems silly to me.

Comment: From the link it says that at first that the links didn't work. But then the update was to remove the boxes altogether. By that release, it's considered status-bydesign.