# Post quality - reputation per question/answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

I'm hoping an SQL guru can whip this out in a jiffy, using stackql or stateoverflow.

I'd like to get a number for each user that represents their reputation over the number of posts they've contributed, to see what their average rep per post is.  This may have already been done, but my searches haven't found it.

Ultimately I'd like to compare my own score against the rest of SO by placing everyone's rep/posts on a scatter plot.  So my own score is about 38 (28102rep/740posts), and a sampling of the top users shows a range of around 18 to 42.  Doubtless my high score is due to me not contributing much for these last several months where questions appear to be getting less rep as the site becomes busier.

Still, I love numbers, and am hoping someone has already done this, or can show a relatively easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Ill one up you, most reputation per keystroke

It needs to be updated though

[Who gets the most reputation per keystroke on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21454/who-gets-the-most-reputation-per-keystroke-on-so)

Comment: Curse my verbosity!  I get 34 characters per rep, which is oddly close to my 32 rep per post...

Answer (score 2):

Most high users will have a relatively *low* rep/post score, because a lot of the rep has been lost to the rep cap.

If you're interested in *votes* per non-CW post, there's the ["all tag" stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats&pagesize=50), although of course you can do the same thing in stackql. It's probably worth looking there first to see whether you find that information interesting :)

Comment: Why is there a rep cap?

Comment: @grieve: That's a question that deserves more discussion than just a comment... Sooner or later I may get round to asking it fully, just to get some debate going...