# The tag "navel-gazing" has no tag wiki and is um...?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

The tag [navel-gazing](/questions/tagged/navel-gazing) has no tag wiki and just 2 (well, now 3) questions.

Please could someone explain what navel gazing is (Ooh, [Wikipedia says Meditation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphaloskepsis)) but I am confused how looking at one's navel links to [the ~ character](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44145/a-last-tribute-to-the-tilde) and a [post quality question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30028/post-quality-reputation-per-question-answer)...?

[image]

Comment: Ok the tag is removed from all questions. Balpha rolled back as my edit for some unknown reason changed things other than the tag removal. He's kindly removed the tag now, however.

Comment: Yeah, I fell into the same trap as @James, know better now. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed the tag from the two other questions.

The tag was used as "tongue-in-cheek", which *can* be ok if it's a well used tag but hardly worth having a tag for two questions asked 5 years ago and likely not going to be used again.

Both questions are otherwise well tagged.

---

Do you want to do yours, or should I :P

Comment: Just as a heads-up, [you were rolled back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/44145/revisions)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/44145/revisions - you didn't :D

Comment: Hey what the... Also, I never did those other edits. Just the tag..?

Comment: I saw some strange edits earlier too...? Post a new bug?

Comment: Maybe it was Community user/scripts doing obvious stuff in with my edit? I've asked Balpha about the tag, not going to start an editing war, especially given he's got a diamond and I've got, well, my coat probably...

Comment: Yeah, "Dear..." is the thing that is automatically removed with attribution to the editor who didn't even.